# BlueStacks: A Kinemaster problem or where is my video exported to?

Tags: export, bluestacks

I've googleing for a while to fix the following problem, but without success. I'm trying to learn to use the app Kinemaster, in my computer (Windows 10) running under the BlueStack emulator.
Apparently, the video I created was successfully exported, but I cannot find it on the computer.
My question is: where is it stored/exported to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your Bluestacks,,,In Home,Library; Click the System apps go to Media Manager, U can find all your exported videos there, and also u can also transfer it to window by clicking the EXPORT TO WINDOWS and Done..